# How to get the name of the embedding struct in Go?

Tags: go, struct, reflection, runtime, embedding

I have a struct `Base` which is embedded in another struct. I want to access the name of the embedding struct dynamically within a method of `Base`.
Here's an example:

```golang
package main

type Base struct{
}

func (b *Base) GetStructName() {
    // want to access which embedding struct called it i.e Test
}

type Test struct {
    Base
}

func main() {
    test := &Test{}
    test.GetStructName()
}
```

I have tried utilizing the `runtime` and `reflect` packages, but unfortunately, they haven't provided the desired outcome.

Comment: You can't, not in any automagic way. If you need Base to know who is embedding it you need the embedder to tell that to the Base explicitly.